# How to Print Some Items in JForm Using JButton

Tags: java, swing, printing, jframe, jbutton

I'm a newbie in coding.
I want to make a shipping label program that printable using JForm Netbeans.
The printable text is in a JPanel.

Already looked for the print action code (which hard to found), finally found it, tried it but all failed.
The error warning said that the method is not applicable.

```
    private void buttonprintActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

        try{
        panelpreview.print(); //error: no suitable method for prints (no argument)
        }

        catch(java.awt.print.PrinterException e){  //error: exception PrinterException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
        System.err.format("No Printer Found", e.getMessage());
        }

}
```

Can you help me so it can work?
Thank you in advance.